# Python Pandas Error: ValueError: Expected "X" fields in line "Y", saw "Z"

Tags: python, excel, numpy

I'm trying to use this code to read in data from an Excel file:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('flielocation.xlsx',  sheetname=None)
```

I get an error that says `ValueError: Expected 9 fields in line 3, saw 8`. How can I fix it?

Comment: I Guess the line 3 has less fields.

Comment: You might try putting a dummy value in that line, 'nan' or whatever would be appropriate in context.

Comment: It's not clear to me why this question was asked in the first place. What is unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `flielocation.xlsx` having only 8 fields on Line 3 when 9 fields were expected.

Add an extra field value to that line; either `NULL`, `0`, or `something`.

Another approach could be to only read the first 8 columns using the [`parse_cols`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) keyword so your code would become:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('flielocation.xlsx',  sheetname=None, parse_cols=8)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this automatically in my code?

Comment: does it even work if you manually fill in a value in to the 9th field on Line 3 ?

Comment: what if your error goes the other way? ValueError: Expected 96 fields in line 1, saw 97 (there really should only be 96 columns in there, and the line that it fails on is the same number of characters in wc as other files / lines that worked fine)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, reading in a csv file using `;` as separator, I'd forgotten to inform python of this. So now I have: `x = pd.read_csv('path/to/file/file.csv', sep = ';')`. Which works file.